# How do i write a program that opens an exe file(spectrawin) and saves the data into a specific name and folder?

Tags: c++

I'm using c++. How do i write a program that opens an exe file(spectrawin) and saves the data into a specific name and folder?

Cheers

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. Do you mean to run the exe file, capture its output and save it as a text file? Under what OS? (Hint: check out the > pipe on the command line in Windows or Unices.)

Comment: yes. you're right. run the exe file, capture its output and then save it as a text file. I'm running windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

This will make a directory called Output, and pipe the output from your executable into a file called output.txt, inside that Output directory.

```
mkdir ("Output");
chdir ("Output");
system ("spectrawin > output.txt");
```

Please note that I do not know what spectrawin does. The above code works with an exe that outputs to the console.

Incidentally, if you need to know where your working directory currently is, use something like:

```
char workingDir [_MAX_PATH];
_getcwd( workingDir, _MAX_PATH );
```

Comment: thanks for the ans. what I understand from it is: |
-the mkdir ("Output"); chdir ("Output"); system ("spectrawin > output.txt"); specifies where the file should be saved to yes?
-as for spectrawin to run, is it char workingDir [_MAX_PATH]; _getcwd( workingDir, _MAX_PATH ); ?

Comment: mkdir ("Output") will actually make the folder exist, like doing "new folder" in an explorer window, and renaming it to "Output". But where will it make it? It will make it inside the current working directory. Where is the current working directory? _getcwd will make a string with its full name in. The first chdir call you make will navigate from that current working directory. So chdir ("Output") would go into that directory you just made, and now the "Output" folder will be your current working directory. Alternatively, chdir ("..") is a special case that goes up one level.

Comment: And finally, system ("spectrawin") simply launches spectrawin. But system ("spectrawin > output.txt") will launch spectrawin, and pipe its output into a file called "output.txt". Where will that file be? It will be in the current working directory. Hope that helps!